# How to show a formatted link in a string in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

In UITextView I have added **UIDataDetectorTypeLink** to detect links in string and it is working fine. But the problem is I have a string like `www.google.com<http://www.google.com>`and it showing as it is. I want to show only `www.google.com`. Is there a way to achieve this?

**Edit:**

It is not specific to google.com. I have given an example of google. String may or may not have the format `Title<url>`. I need to handle this format if that is there.

Comment: You can put a check on string that if it contains "<",">" then it should only select the string within "<" and ">" before passing it to UIDataDetectorTypeLink

Comment: You have to remove <http://www.google.com> or add space between www.google.com and <http://www.google.com>

Comment: i think you need to use `NSScanner` to scan the input string to find `Title<url>` this pattern and create attributed string.

Comment: Try NSRegularExpression. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Google"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"http://www.google.com" range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
yourTextView.attributedText = str;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method to do this. writing a method can keep your code clean and easy to read.

```
- (NSString *)cutString:(NSString *)sourceString {
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = @"www.google.com".length;
    return [sourceString substringWithRange:range];
}

//call that method to subString
NSString myStr = [self cutString:@"www.google.com<http://www.google.com>"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have created a sample parser with `NSScanner`,

```
- (void)textFormattingForLink {

    NSString *inputString = @"some prefix string Google<www.google.com> and Stackoverflow<www.stackoverflow.com>";
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:inputString];
    NSMutableAttributedString *outputString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
        NSString *prefixOfLink;
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&prefixOfLink];

        __block NSString *lastWord = nil;

        [prefixOfLink enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [prefixOfLink length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange subrange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
            lastWord = substring;
            *stop = YES;
        }];
        NSScanner *preficScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:prefixOfLink];
        NSString *prefixOfLinkWord;
        [preficScanner scanUpToString:lastWord intoString:&prefixOfLinkWord];
        [outputString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:prefixOfLinkWord]];

        [scanner scanString:@"<" intoString:NULL];
        NSString *linkString;
        [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&linkString];
        NSMutableAttributedString * link = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lastWord];
        [link addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: linkString range: NSMakeRange(0, link.length)];

        [outputString appendAttributedString:link];
        [scanner scanString:@">" intoString:NULL];
        [outputString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "]];
    }
    [self.textView setAttributedText:outputString];
}
```

the output is [image]

Answer (score 0):

@Akhilrajtr 
Thank you for you NSScanner implementation, it inspired this NSAttributedString category. Hope it helps someone!

```
- (void)setStringWithLinks:(NSString*)string
{
    if (string.length == 0)  
        return;

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];

    while(![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        NSString * textBeforeLink;
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<a href=\"" intoString:&textBeforeLink];

        NSString * linkURL;
        [scanner scanString:@"<a href=\"" intoString:NULL];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"\">" intoString:&linkURL];

        NSString * linkText;
        [scanner scanString:@"\">" intoString:NULL];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"</a>" intoString:&linkText];
        [scanner scanString:@"</a>" intoString:NULL];


        [self appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textBeforeLink]];

        if (linkText.length >0)
        {
            NSMutableAttributedString * link = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:linkText];
            NSRange foundRange = NSMakeRange(0, link.length);
            [link addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value: linkURL range: foundRange];
            [link addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:foundRange];
            [link addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13] range:foundRange];

            [self appendAttributedString:link];

            [self appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "]];
        }
    }
}
```